# ADC Burst mode in LPC2119 not working

Tags: microcontroller, adc, arm, lpc

I have been trying to work with ADC using ARM 7 LPC 2119  in burst mode however this functionality is not working.

My code is as follows:

```
    ADCR = 0X0121090F; // Start A/D Conversion

    //Wait for the conversion to complete               
    while(!(ADDR & 0x80000000)); 
    {....}
```

I am also scanning 4 channels from AIN0 to AIN3, however on debugging I see nothing:

[image]

As can be seen, the ADDR value does not change when there is an input to AIN0. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On scanning through the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10114.pdf) Page 305, it is listed that **START bits must be 0 when burst mode is on**.

[image]

In your case I am seeing that the burst mode bit *and* the start bits are set to 1. This is wrong and will not work.

ADCR register must be configured as follows: `ADCR = 0X0021090F;`